# Google Maps API - Large Circle Extends To Gray Area Above Map

Tags: google-maps

When I use the API to draw a circle near th poles, the area of the circle extends to an infinite distance in the gray area above the map. Is there a way to prevent the circle from extending into the gray area?

Answer (score 0):

No, this is a property of the Mercator projection that is used to represent the Earth in 2D http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mercator_projection.

Comment: Thanks but I'm looking for a Google API solution at which I can cut off polygons at certain points.